# PHP foreach loops

Tags: php

This is making me insane.  I've validated my input/outputs, and I'm still getting unexpected behavior.  It should be 2, but it's doing numa numa.  What am I missing?

**Input:**

```
data
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lineId] => 1
            [quantity] => 2
            [costPerItem] => 16.585
            [itemId] => 1
        )

)
```

**Code:**

```
printr( $data, 'data' );
foreach( $data as $i => $value ){
    foreach( $value as $key => $a ){
        echo 'key: '.$key.' - a: '.$a.'<br />';
        ( $key == 'quantity' ) ? $dataQuantity[$i] = $a : $dataQuantity[$i] = 'numanuma'; 
    }
}
printr( $dataQuantity, 'data quantity' );
```

**Output:**

```
key: lineId - a: 1
key: quantity - a: 2
key: costPerItem - a: 16.585
key: itemId - a: 1

data quantity
Array
(
    [0] => numanuma
)
```

Comment: I don't see any `break` statement in your code.

Comment: I'm not breaking the foreach loop here, and I shouldn't have to.  I skinnied the code down trying to debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with this.

First, you're setting the value `$dataQuantity[$i]` in your sub-loop but `$i` is incremented in your outer loop.

When your code sees 'quantity' it may set `$dataQuantity[$i]` to `2`, but then it sees `itemId` and overrides `$dataQuantity[$i]` since `$i` hasn't changed.

Secondly, you should change your ternary if statement to this:

```
$dataQuantity[$i] = ( $key == 'quantity' ) ? $a : 'numanuma';
```

*That doesn't factor for what I mentioned previously*.

Here's a working sample:

```
printr( $data, 'data' );
foreach( $data as $i => $value ){
    foreach( $value as $key => $a ){
        if ($key == 'quantity') {
            $dataQuantity[$i] = $a;
            break;
        }
    }
}
printr( $dataQuantity, 'data quantity' );
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the key itemId is after the quantity key. So it was set to 2 but the loop after it was set to numanuma.

Try this:

```
printr( $data, 'data' );
foreach( $data as $i => $value ){
    foreach( $value as $key => $a ){
        echo 'key: '.$key.' - a: '.$a.'<br />';
        if( $key == 'quantity' )
        { 
            $dataQuantity[$i] = $a; 
        } 
    }
}
printr( $dataQuantity, 'data quantity' );
```

Comment: Wow, i added the ternary trying to debug, and that was a stupid mistake.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You assign "numanuma" if the key is not "quantity". After the "quantity" key, some keys are *not* quantity, so "numanuma" is assigned over the value of `$a`.

Short answer, add an extra check and a flag to check if `$dataQuantity[$i]` has already been assigned correctly before assigning "numanuma".

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator not used for assigning value please read this:

> Note: Please note that the ternary operator is a statement, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of a
>   statement. This is important to know if you want to return a variable
>   by reference. The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a
>   return-by-reference function will therefore not work and a warning is
>   issued in later PHP versions.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)